# Copy macro from personal workbook to other workbook

Tags: excel, module, copy-paste, vba

I need to copy module1 from my personal workbook to another workbook programmatically. I get a report generated by our ERP system that is just a bunch of data in an excel spreadsheet and the macro in my personal.xlsb formats, sorts, and filters the data to make it usable. It's a lot of steps, so I just wrote a macro to do the whole shebang, and I saved that macro in my personal because this report is generated whenever we run it in the ERP system, i.e. it has no home and it's a unique file every time we get it.

I need the person I'm  making this for to be able to run a macro and have the macro:

- copy module1 from personal.xlsb and put it in the report
- save the report as the day of the week we ran the macro on it.

I can't run this code without getting an error. The most common one I see is that it can't access TRANSCT.xls

I have changed the trust center settings to trust access to the VBA project object model. I ran this code once on my computer and it ran fine. Every time after that on my computer and other computers it does not work.

```
Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Activate
  Dim wbkSource As Workbook, wbkTarget As Workbook

Set wbkSource = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB")
Set wbkTarget = Workbooks("TRANSCT.XLS")

wbkSource.VBProject.VBComponents("module1").Export ("c:\tmp\\MrXL1.bas")
wbkTarget.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("c:\tmp\\MrXL1.bas")
```

The name of the report is always TRANSCT.xls
It does not open as read-only
The module in personal.xlsb is in fact named Module1

I'm losing my mind here guys.

Comment: Why don't you copy the macro once to the computer of the person you are doing this for. This should be a one-time job or are you changing the macro a lot? Then it might be better tocreat an AddIn which you distribute.

Comment: The personal macro is on the person's computer, however, part of the macro adds buttons with onactions that do certain things to the report. Once the macro saves off the report, I need the VBA to go with it so that those buttons work. Otherwise, when it saves the report and they open it and click a button, the macros attached are not found (obviously), thus the need to copy the macros over before saving.

Comment: Then I would suggest you create an AddIn and distrubute that. The buttons with onactions can also call macros from the AddIn.

Comment: I guess it's just hard for me to believe that there isn't a neat VBA way to just copy a macro from one workbook to another.